# Генерация разных не равных чисел JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, случайные-числа

```
var arrmain = 
[
//Тут элементы массива
];
nlink1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrmain.length);          
nlink2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrmain.length);  
nlink3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrmain.length);
```

Как сгенерировать не равные друг другу рандомные числа в заданном диапазоне?

Comment: что дальше будет с этим числами?

Comment: Они будут использованы как номера элементов массива arrmain

Comment: какое количество чисел нужно сгенерировать по отношению к размеру массива?

Comment: Нужно из общего числа элементов массива  сгенерировать шесть не равных чисел

Comment: сколько элементов всего? это случайно не карточная игра?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, господи, просто нужно сгенерировать рандомный массив чисел из диапазона, чтобы каждое число в нём не повторялось.  Зачем все эти вопросы?

Comment: что бы понять на сколько случайными должны быть числа. классический вариант решения задачи с картами - это перемешивание массива.

Comment: Количество элементов может быть разным. А их них нужно лишь шесть.